# SignalA not getting Connected once Connection state went to Reconnection

Tags: java, android, signalr

I am using SignalA android client library in my android application for getting real time data push from server.

i am able to establish the connection with server using HubConnection specified in SignalA framework.  After some time(10 or 5 mins once), SignalA tries to reconnect the connection, that i could captured in the callback method(onStateChanged) of HubConnection. Once the connection state was reached 'Reconnecting' state, it is not connecting with the Server further.  It always retains the same state as 'Reconnecting'. it is not establishing the connection again.

In this scenario, i am failing to get push from server.

Can anyone provide the solution on this like how can i establish the connection again?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new version of SignalA. This was a bug that is hopefully fixed in the new version.